# How to enable Arabic/UTF8 labelling in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, arabic

I have data in GeoJSON that contains Arabic in some attribute when reading the attribute

```
info.push(features[i].get('Name'));
```

I get this:

[image]
Unreadable how to enable UTF8 or I don't know...

Comment: In openlayers GIS

Answer (score 4):

I was getting data from GeoJSON file ,and it was a problem of encoding characters in it at first place.
I specified "utf-8" in the creation of my GeoJSON file ,and it worked well, thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

OpenLayers 2 does not have any problems with arabic characters, see e.g. [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrikais/ry8222p2/2/).

However, you will need to specify the correct character encoding in your HTML file, something like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ...
<head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Also make sure your files are indeed in UTF-8 encoding, of course.